# Black screen beteen GRUB and login screen

Tags: boot

So i Bought a Lenovo Legion Y530 and installed Ubuntu 18.04 Lts.
So far so good, update nvidia drivers and got everything up and running.
The issue is that i get a black screen for about 20-30 second before the login screen, i hade tried everything. Changing modeset etc but this doesnt go away do you guys know something about this?
I have a m.2 ssd so this long bort shouldnt be happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see what is happening during the 20 to 30 seconds use:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Find the line that starts with:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash
```

and change it to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="noplymouth
```

Leave the rest of the line as is.

Now save the file and exit `gedit`

Run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Now when you reboot you will see the messages scroll by as the kernel boots up. If it gets stuck on one message for more than a second note it and add it to your question.

For a detailed time break down of your boot use:

```
systemd-analyze blame
```

The longest running boot commands are listed first. Use <kbd>Q</kbd> to exit the command.

---

### Systemd log messages

After completing above steps this error is revealed during boot up:

```
WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
```

Arch Linux references this error [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=231357).

Unix & Linux describes LVM setup errors [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/199164/error-run-lvm-lvmetad-socket-connect-failed-no-such-file-or-directory-but).

Comment: I get, failed to Connect lvmetad, gamling back to scanning.

Comment: @AllamoOlsson I've updated my answer with your error message. It appears you installed using `LVM` option which isn't required for the average user. It's designed for partitions spanning multiple disks like a server would use. You can reinstall without LVM option if you have a new installation and nothing to loose.